# React: Почему я не получаю данные из input?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hook-form

Мне нужно получить обьект с импутами, для дальнейшей валидации, а получаю я пустой обьект. В чем может быть проблема? (Использую react-hook-form ^7.39.1)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**Компонент формы**

```
const { register, handleSubmit, errors } = useForm({
    mode: "onBlur",
  })

 const onSubmit = (data) => {
    console.log(data);
 }

 <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)} noValidate className={ styles.form }>
     <div className={`${styles.form__content_data} ${styles.content_data}`}>
         <div className={ styles.content_data__wrapper }>
           <Input ref={() => register()} id="firstName" type="text" label="First Name" name="firstName" />
           <Input ref={() => register()} id="weight" type="number" label="Weight" name="weight" />
           <Input ref={() => register()} id="age" type="number" label="Age" name="age" />
        </div>
     </div>
     <PrimaryButton type="submit">
        отправить заявку
      </PrimaryButton>
 </form>
```

**Компонент инпута**

```
export const Input = forwardRef((props, ref) => {
  return(
    <input type="text" ref={ref} {...props} />
  );
});
```

Comment: А `register` разве верно использован? `{...register('firstName')}` задаст нужные пропсы, вот это `ref={() => register()}` выглядит неверным. https://react-hook-form.com/api/useform/register#main

Comment: Я учусь на видео 2019 года. Но спасибо, что объяснили!